Setting the show_touches system property
I'm trying to return a boolean and set the system property'show_touches'. I have system level permissions(my device is rooted and I used lucky patcher to modify system signature). I'm using android 8.1
This is my boolean it didn't return anything
     public boolean isShowTapsOn(){
        //return System.getProperty("show_touches").equals("1");
        int showTouches = Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),"show_touches",0);
        return showTouches ==1;
    }

This is my method
      void setTapsOnOff(){
        int tapsInt;
        if(isAdbOn()){tapsInt=0;}else{tapsInt=1;}
        Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), "show_touches", tapsInt);
    }


I figured it out had to change target SDK to 22. Then change code to void setTapsOnOff(){
int tapsInt;
if(isShowTapsOn()){tapsInt=0;}else{tapsInt=1;}
/try{
Process tProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","settings put system show_touches "+tapsInt});
}catch( Exception e){}/
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),"show_touches",tapsInt);
}
